# POST http://localhost:55703/ValidStep1 404 (Not Found)

Tags: c#, jquery, post, razor, http-status-code-404

I want to go to another page when I click on a button, but when I click, nothing happen & I'm stuck on the initial page + I have this error :

POST http://localhost:55703/Home/ValidStep1 404 (Not Found)

here's my code :

HomeController.cs

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ValidStep1(Dictionary<string, List<string>> listUsers){
//some code
}
```

Index.cshtml

```js
jQuery.post('/Home/ValidStep1', { listUsers: listUser }, function (data) {
  if (data) {
    document.location.replace("@ViewBag.nextStep");
  }
  else {
    document.location.replace("@ViewBag.errorStep");
  }
});
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: No but it doesn't even find the method "ValidStep1" so...

Comment: Depending on how you have your endpoint routing set up, the url you are looking for may need to contain the controller name. Try: http://localhost:55703/Home/ValidStep1

Comment: Just updated.. :/

Comment: See if service is running by looking for port 55703 by running frow cmd.exe >Netstat -a  Error 404 may occur if you need a secure connection HTTPS and you are only using HTTP.

Comment: Do you guys have an idea why it's works now with .ajax() but not with .post() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now it works with this following code. BUT I DON'T KNOW WHY. It's like... the same as above.

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '@Url.Action("ValidStep1", "Home")',
  data: { listUsers: listUser },
  success: function (data) {
      document.location.replace("@ViewBag.nextStep");
  },
  error: function () {
      document.location.replace("@ViewBag.errorStep");
  }
});
```